# Facing issue in implementing horizontal and vertical scrollview using autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, autolayout

I am implementing horizontal and vertical scrollview in my application. My Outer scrollview is scrolling vertically and my inner scrollview is scrolling horizontally.

I have set layout as shown in below image.

[image]

Now I set content size of my outer scrollview as follows

```
self.outerScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.outerScrollView.frame.size.height);
```

I have set view's width as 460 even though I am able to scroll screen in iphone4s and iphone5 simulator. Actually it does not scroll on both of these devices.

If temporary I remove my inner view then scrolling does not happen.

Why am I facing this problem?

Comment: Did you notice you have a scrollview in a scrollview? It won't work properly.

Comment: yes I have a scrollview in scrollview then how to implement such kind of scenario

Comment: Why won't you just set 1 scrollView and make it possible to scroll both vertically and horizontally in it? Also where do you set contentSize in code? In which UIKit method?

Comment: @Vive:Actually my inner scroolview shows horizontal scrolling of images and vertical scrollview(outer scrollview) shows detail about images so it is required to implement two scrollview

Comment: 1. You should REALLY do it in collectionView instead of scrollViews. Reusable cells will be a memory saver for these images. 2. Where do you set scrollview contentSize? In which UIKit method?

Comment: @Vive:In past I have implemented such kind of scenario without using auto layout but right now I am facing issue with auto layout

Comment: @Vive:In my viewcontroller file and in viewDidLoad method

Comment: You can do things better or worse. `ScrollView` keeps everything in memory all the time, while `CollectionView` keeps only visible cells. Because of this, solution with `ScrollView` will work but will be rather bad code quality and in case of many images may cause memory warnings in your app and eventually even crash it. `viewDidLoad` is called once and you should change it after every `bounds` change of your `controller`. You should use `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method instead. Anyway, I misadvise using `ScrollViews` in this case - I wouldn't accept it in codeReview.